# Restore a previous version of a file using the aws.s3 package in R

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a function in R with the package aws.s3 that allows previous versions of a file (object) to be restored (from AWS S3's versioning feature). I haven't found a solution yet - but if anyone has one, or has done this before any help would be much appreciated!

I think a good start would be the ability to be able to retrieve the versions of individual bucket objects, using get_versions - I've tried `get_verions(bucket="bucket/path_to_object")` and `get_verions(bucket="bucket", path = "path_to_object)` but I don't think either of these work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't technically answer the question, but you can do it easily with the [paws package](https://github.com/paws-r/paws/). You can just do

```
s3$list_object_versions("bucket",Prefix = prefix)

s3$get_object("bucket",Key=key,VersionId = vid)
```